# Is their a way to list the copyright claims of your video on Youtube using Youtube's API?

Tags: youtube-api

When you upload a video to YouTube you may get a **Includes copyrighted content** flag in the video manager. Then when you go and check the video you see a message under the "copyright" section:
**You have x copyright claims on your video.** and below this is a **Details** section displaying interesting information like: 
"CONTENT","CLAIMANT","POLICY" and it shows the time region where this claimed content is located in the video. What i would like to know is if Youtube's or Google's API can give us this same information?

Comment: DId you find how to strict copyright video from youtube data api?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Send HTTP request using this format:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

If successful, this method returns a response body with this sample [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource):

```
"contentDetails": {
    "licensedContent": boolean,
    "regionRestriction": {
      "allowed": [
        string
      ],
      "blocked": [
        string
      ]
    },
"status": {
    "privacyStatus": string,
    "publishAt": datetime,
    "license": string,
    "publicStatsViewable": boolean
  }
```

Comment: The `licensedContent` status is not working that way if you mean that. For example video id **ZbGuxGGOIV0** contains copyright claimed but this status is `false`, but the video id **dYQ2IyMuPes** does not contain copyright claimed but this status is `true`. I think it is about for copyrighted owner.